# Creating flash like animations with Canvas and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

This is a "where can I start" type question.

I'm in process of learning HTML5 and Canvas work but have a feeling that I'm looking in the wrong area.

I would like to learn how to create cartoon type flash-like responsive animations. Imagine this teddy bear:
[image: teddy bear image]

When I point my mouse at it I want to make him walk across the screen by implementing my "moving feet" animations etc..When click, I want him to wave his paw.

With HTML5 and Javascript I can make him move/float across but I can't find the way to actually ANIMATE the movements.

Do I create small .mp4 files? Do I create a bunch of images to loop through them? Animated GIFs? I would like to stay away from flash ofcourse...

I thought HTML5 with Canvas animation would allow me to achieve what I want but other than drawing simple shape animations and Video work I can't seem to find tutorials or "How to" articles.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do or do I need to look elsewhere? I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Edit: I ran into the following game while doing research: http://www.cuttherope.ie/
How, for example is the monster animated in something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the purpose of the exercise is to learn HTML5 and canvas then the following is probably not for you. If you need to create your teddy animation as quickly and easily as possible, and deliver it using standards based technologies, then I would suggest you download and explore the preview of [Adobe Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/). It's a motion and interaction design tool similar to Flash (timeline and keyframes) which outputs a combination of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I haven't played with the preview version but I'm pretty sure it will be capable of producing the sort of animation you're talking about.

**Update:**

You might also want to consider [Zoë](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2011/02/zoe-export-swf-animation-as-easeljs-spritesheets.html) which can be used to export SWF animations directly to sprite sheets. It was created by the team which developed the `Canvas` library [easel.js](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) and can export the accompanying frame data as either JSON or easel.js. It will allow you to create your animations in Flash (which, let's face it, is still the best web animation tool around) but render them using HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of Edge. I just spent a few hours learning about it. While it looks like a great product it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking to do. Like I said above, with Edge it looks like I'll be able to slide the bear across the screen but I don't see it being used for creating custom animations, such as waiving hands or moving feet while walking. Here is an example of what it basically does: http://edge.adobe.com/resources/ninja/ninja.html

Comment: Like I said, I haven't played with Edge for a while so will have to defer to you. However, I would be really, really surprised if you couldn't use it to create a simple animation such as the one you've described. It's been designed for exactly that purpose and should remove the grunt work of animating something manually as described in the answers by Brian and Simon.

Answer (score 8):

Canvas will do you well here.

Animation is typically done merely by cycling through different PNG files (or a spritemap with different images). [Here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrjyq/72) I did not long ago that shows a simple animation on the canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();

var drawTile = function(x, y, tile, width, height) {
    context.drawImage(image, (tile % 6) * width, Math.floor(tile / 6) * height, width, height, x, y, width, height);
};

image.onload = function() {
    // draw all 12 tiles:
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        context.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        drawTile(0, 0, i, 48, 32);
        i++;
        if (i > 11) i = 0;
    }, 85);
}
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkWe2.png';
```

If you look at the image in the example, you get an idea of what a sprite map for animation looks like:

[image]

Cycling thought the sprites in such an image based on a timer is all that's needed!

---

Making and moving clickable, selectable objects on the canvas takes a bit of footwork. There's nothing built in for object detection on the canvas. But if you've done programming before it isn't too hard, and I've written a [popular tutorial on the matter](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) that serves as a very gentle introduction. It should help you out.

Other than that, your best resource is, of course, Stack Overflow. :) We'll always be glad to answer individual questions as you come across them.

Comment: I'm a .net web dev but I don't have much experience with animations and such tasks. Give me some time to work with your tutorial. brb :)
One question I have about working with Spritemap. Is it only effective for tiny images like what you've used in your example ?
...What if my image is 500x400 or so ( random example ) ? I imagine the sprite map file is going to get quite large.
Same with an image library.. Am I really going to keep 100s of files in a web folder and cycle through them ? Seems odd and not very productive.

Comment: 500x400 as a spritemap size or as the size of a single sprite? Spritemaps are effective all over the web because they reduce the number of requests. They're typically used with small images but not always. Look at this one that Youtube is using: http://s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflMLqC23.png Or the one Amazon is using: http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/BeaconSprite-US-01._V141013396_.png or Google+: https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/sprites/ribbon-nav-common-c4ff9240a2b70f779ed0dd6da60e5b15.png

Comment: Sounds like this can only be applied to small, thumbnail size, very short animations really, not if my bear that I want to animate for example is 500x400 size itself ( not the whole sprite map, just the image itself ). What do you think about creating animated gifs in P-shop and using them on a canvas for animations ? Is it going to make  a cartoon way "too heavy" size wise ?

Comment: Take a look at the following game sample developed in HTML5: http://www.cuttherope.ie/
How do you think the little monster is animated?

Comment: Looks like canvas animations with html and background images accounting for the majority of graphics.  As for the animations, hard to tell with minified js but it look like just straight up grunt work and math. Over 10,000 lines of javascript in ctr.js is no small feat.

Comment: If you need an example of a canvas game with very few lines of code you can look at my work in progress here: http://cloudstork.com/temp/game.html It's a game I'm making for future tutorials. The code is made to be easy to understand, but of course its not done yet, so there may be a few issues, but its definitely smaller than cut the rope :)

Comment: Im not looking to make games. Just used that as an example above. So what do you think is the best approach to implement animations to larger images? Larger than sprites shown.

Comment: Possibly making a video, but it reaaally depends on the details of what you're trying to accomplish. There may be a better way altogether if you want to move something large

Comment: "the better way" is exactly what im looking for! Hopefully some one knows!

Answer (score 2):

For animations, [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) is nice. It's even got a few [physics engine plugin](http://chandlerprall.github.com/Physijs/)s.

Also, take a look at parts of [HTML5 Game Development](http://www.html5gamedevelopment.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll quickly bow to a more educated answer, but I would guess what you want to do may be a little too much for canvas/javascript performance in the browser.

If you're an animator by trade it might not seem like such a tedious task, but I imagine you would be writing a lot of code to animate intricate paths and fill them and etc...

I'm sure you've researched, but there are numerous javascript canvas libraries out there. [Paper js](http://paperjs.org/) comes to mind or [processing js](http://processingjs.org/).  They might point you in a decent direction if you check out their examples/capabilities concerning paths and animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, more and more it seems to me that "a little too much" is what it is but I wonder what do animators use today with Flash no longer being liable and not supported by mobile devices...

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there are two problems to tackle:

1. Give the bear motion within itself (legs at a minimum)
2. Move the bear across the screen

Tackling these two gets you the appearance of the bear walking across the screen (as opposed to just moving across the screen or walking in place). It sounds like you've already tackled problem #1.

To tackle #2, your best bet is to have an image per-frame. Trying to draw the bear in a different position for each frame is a waste of time. If you preload the frame images, you can take the cost once at the beginning and them you're just displaying a different image as he walks.

Now, is this a job for canvas? I don't know. I'm thinking you could probably build what I've described in "old school" HTML/JavaScript/CSS. The platform is up to you--but frames--and more specifically an image for each frame--are the key concept here.

Comment: Actually it's other way around. From OP: "With HTML5 and Javascript I can make him move/float across but I can't find the way to actually ANIMATE the movements."
The problem is how to make the character animate, to appear that it's actually walking or waving. Small video ? A bunch of combined jpgs ? A spritemap was suggested above ?

Comment: No, I think I got it (see my problem #1). I just laid both parts out to make it clear that there are two separate problems to solve, and that you've already solved one.